# Jest: Mocking a component out of the fluent ui node module

Tags: jestjs

i am currently in a situation, where I am not able to fully test one of my components, because it renders a fluentUi DropDown and I have trouble to test if the correct items are bound to the dropdown.

What I wanted to try is to mock the fluent ui DropDown, but I do not get very far.

As far as I understood, it should be possible to mock a node module like this:

```
let module = require.requireActual("@fluentUi/react"); 
module.DropDown= jest.fn((props: IDropDownProps) => { return <>... some content</>; }); 
jest.mock("@fluentUi/react", () => { return module; });
```

But this does not have any impact on my tests. Am I on the right track or did I misunderstand something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have investigated on this topic a bit more and ended up publishing a little example, where I am mocking the ui fabric modal.

It works fine. The mock only renders its properties, so I can assert within the snapshot, if the real life Modal gets consumed correctly.

https://github.com/Link631/MockingModulesWithJest/tree/master/mocking_with_jest